# High jitter using AirPort Extreme 5th gen

Tags: wireless-networking

Does anyone know of a way to reduce jitter on an 5th generation AirPort Extreme? I've been having major issues with FaceTime Audio and Skype calls because of it. If I bypass the router, the jitter drops from ~90ms to ~10ms. (The reason I still have some when my connection is direct is because the ISP uses wireless technology due to the rural environment.)

Someone told me I should disconnect my devices because eight is too many to have on the wireless network. Is that necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I can think of three likely culprits you still need to track down:

1. Frequency conflict with your rooftop WISP gear. A lot of rooftop WISP gear, whether Wi-Fi-based or not, usually uses the 5GHz band, especially the high end (5.8GHz end) of the band, which is where Wi-Fi puts channels 149-165. So look up the make and model of your rooftop WISP gear to see what frequencies it can use, or better yet, have your WISP tell you which frequency range the box on your roof is using. If you have access to a spectrum analyzer such as a Wi-Spy DBx, you can actually see for yourself which frequencies are in use. Then manually set your base station's 5GHz radio to some channel far away from that.
2. General Wi-Fi-related jitter that can happen on any not-perfectly-clean channel. For both your 2.4GHz and 5GHz channel, make sure you're selecting a clean channel. The AirPort Base Station tries to do this automatically at boot, but sometimes it can have a hard time sensing non-Wi-Fi interferers, or maybe the interfering devices weren't transmitting at the time the base station booted. So pick a clean channel. A spectrum analyzer would be the best tool for the job, because unlike a Wi-Fi-scanner like inSSIDer, a spectrum analyzer will pick up non-Wi-Fi interferers. If you don't have access to a spectrum analyzer, use a tool like inSSIDer to at least avoid other Wi-Fi networks. And then, for the sake of testing, turn off all your other wireless devices (I mean really power off their Wi-Fi radios, don't just put them to sleep). Now run your test and see how your jitter is.
3. Jitter related to the time it takes your base station to process each packet, regardless of wired or wireless. Considering plugging in your machine to a wired Ethernet LAN port of the base station, to eliminate Wi-Fi-related jitter all together. If you still have jitter problems, keep your machine connected via Ethernet and temporarily turn off NAT on your base station, making it just a transparent bridge. Give your Skype/FaceTime machine the public IP address your base station's WAN port would have had (you'll need to configure your base station to not use that address for now, while you're testing). This tests lets you know if the base station's NAT engine is the problem, as opposed to just being about the base station in general.

Comment: @Jacob How did it go?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I ended up using Apple's hidden Wireless Diagnostics tool to scan the channels around me. It said the best were 3 and 4 so I changed it to 3 and tried again. The jitter was a lot more consistent (didn't jump to 150ms suddenly) and ended with 39ms. I tested it once more and got 300ms. Ethernet isn't an option since the router is in someone else's office in the house — it'd be a 50 foot cable.